# Lost connection with my Github repositories?

Tags: github

I did git process at ~/Desktop.

The process is like this:

```
git init

git remote add origin https://github.com/developerHaneum/watch.git

git remote -v

(That's when I knew something was wrong, so I deleted the '.git' file)

ls -al

rm -r .git

ls

(Confirm that the '.git' file is gone)

(I've confirmed that the connection to the the 'watch' repository has been lost)

git remote -v

(The result was like this : 'git remote -v
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git')
```

I want to know exactly when the connection with the repository is lost. Experts, are you really **disconnected**?

Answer (score 1):

It happened when you deleted your `.git` directory. The existence of `.git` is what makes git recognise the files in the parent directory of `.git` as belonging to a git repo, and the files in it store all the information about your local repo, the remotes it's connected to, etc. If you had any local changes you wanted to keep, they're gone (unless you've got the changes in the current state of your files - but unpushed branches and commits are gone). Your directory is not just unaware of your remote, it's not being recognised as a git repo anymore.

I suggest you start over and figure out what was wrong with `git remote -v` that gave you the idea to delete `.git`.

By the way, since the `.` in `.git` makes this a hidden directory in Linux, `ls` will not show it even if it's there. You need to use `ls -a` to include hidden directories in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You have delete this git file so it reports not a git repository.I think you can run `git init` to start a new one